# Error with GetHDFS processor with nifi

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-nifi

I am trying to get files from HDFS directory with apache nifi GetHDFS processor; however, I am getting the error in the nifi-app.log whenever I try to run the job

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://XXX:8020/user/sample_b.csv, expected: file:///
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:649)

Any one has any idea what is causing the error?

Comment: Did you configure the "Hadoop Configuration Resources" property in GetHDFS to point to your core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml ?

Comment: Thank you Bryan; I was able to get through when I added the core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml files.